# Using custom reporters with the maven surefire plugin

Tags: maven, testng, surefire

I'm trying to use a custom reporter for TestNG with the maven surefire plugin. I already have a custom listener and that seems to get picked up. However, it doesn't look like the custom reporter is being used at all:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>com.mystuff.test.TestNGListener</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>reporter</name>
                <value>com.mystuff.test.MyEmailableReporter</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured this out. It looked like the following doesn't work at all:

```
<property>
    <name>reporter</name>
    <value>com.mystuff.test.MyEmailableReporter</value>
</property>
```

in spite of documentation to the contrary. In the `TestNG` class it appears that there is a method called `TestNG#addListener(IReporter listener)`, which contrary to its name, accepts a report which implements `IReporter`. Maven Surefire (v2.12.1) calls this method to add listeners and reports. However, it doesn't look for reports under a property with name `reporter`. Instead, you have to add your custom reporter to the `listener` property:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
        <properties>
            <property>
                <name>listener</name>
                <value>com.mystuff.test.TestNGListener,com.mystuff.test.MyEmailableReporter</value>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Not very intuitive.