# Maven-surefire. How to adjust the level of detail of the report?

Tags: testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I use the emailable-report.html file to send a test report to the email. I do not want detailed information on successful tests (this is the default behavior). Can I somehow customize this?

Property surefire.testng.verbose don`t change this begavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because `EmailableReporter2` doesn't allow configuration.

But you can modify it [from the source](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/EmailableReporter2.java) and use it as your own `EmailableReporter`.
You'll just have to declare it as a listener in your `pom.xml`: [Using custom reporters with the maven surefire plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835790/using-custom-reporters-with-the-maven-surefire-plugin#11837438)