# eclipse - testng the method is undefined for the type Utils

Tags: java, eclipse, testng

I am copying pasting code from [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/reporters/TestHTMLReporter.java), the whole file, and then I would like to make changes to it and implement `IReporter` and I have done all necessary imports in my java file.
All the errors were gone except one  related to below import:

`import org.testng.internal.Utils;`

The error is

```
The method longStackTrace(Throwable, boolean) is undefined for the type Utils   

The method shortStackTrace(Throwable, boolean) is undefined for the type Utils
```

These two are defined , I can see it [here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.testng/testng/6.11/org/testng/internal/Utils.html) and [here](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/blob/master/src/main/java/org/testng/internal/Utils.java) . I tried to clean the project , restart eclipse but nothing worked. 
in `pom.xml`

```
<testng.version>6.10</testng.version>
 <dependency>
             <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
             <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
             <version>${testng.version}</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
             <scope>compile</scope> //tried this also
  </dependency>
```

below is the class

```
package firsttestngpackage;

import java.util.Map;

//import org.apache.xml.serializer.utils.Utils;

import org.testng.IReporter;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.reporters.TestHTMLReporter;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestRunner;
import org.testng.internal.Utils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;



public class CustomReport  implements IReporter {

     @Override
        public void generateReport(List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites,
                                   String outputDirectory) {

        }

     public static void generateTable(PrintWriter pw, String title,
              Collection<ITestResult> tests, String cssClass, Comparator<ITestResult> comparator)
          {
            pw.append("<table width='100%' border='1' class='invocation-").append(cssClass).append("'>\n")
              .append("<tr><td colspan='4' align='center'><b>").append(title).append("</b></td></tr>\n")
              .append("<tr>")
              .append("<td><b>Test method</b></td>\n")
              .append("<td width=\"30%\"><b>Exception</b></td>\n")
              .append("<td width=\"10%\"><b>Time (seconds)</b></td>\n")
              .append("<td><b>Instance</b></td>\n")
              .append("</tr>\n");

            if (tests instanceof List) {
              Collections.sort((List<ITestResult>) tests, comparator);
            }

            // User output?
            String id;
            Throwable tw;

            for (ITestResult tr : tests) {
              pw.append("<tr>\n");

              // Test method
              ITestNGMethod method = tr.getMethod();

              String name = method.getMethodName();
              pw.append("<td title='").append(tr.getTestClass().getName()).append(".")
                .append(name)
                .append("()'>")
                .append("<b>").append(name).append("</b>");

              // Test class
              String testClass = tr.getTestClass().getName();
              if (testClass != null) {
                pw.append("<br>").append("Test class: ").append(testClass);

                // Test name
                String testName = tr.getTestName();
                if (testName != null) {
                  pw.append(" (").append(testName).append(")");
                }
              }

              // Method description
              if (! Utils.isStringEmpty(method.getDescription())) {
                pw.append("<br>").append("Test method: ").append(method.getDescription());
              }

              Object[] parameters = tr.getParameters();
              if (parameters != null && parameters.length > 0) {
                pw.append("<br>Parameters: ");
                for (int j = 0; j < parameters.length; j++) {
                  if (j > 0) {
                    pw.append(", ");
                  }
                  pw.append(parameters[j] == null ? "null" : parameters[j].toString());
                }
              }

              //
              // Output from the method, created by the user calling Reporter.log()
              //
              {
                List<String> output = Reporter.getOutput(tr);
                if (null != output && output.size() > 0) {
                  pw.append("<br/>");
                  // Method name
                  String divId = "Output-" + tr.hashCode();
                  pw.append("\n<a href=\"#").append(divId).append("\"")
                    .append(" onClick='toggleBox(\"").append(divId).append("\", this, \"Show output\", \"Hide output\");'>")
                    .append("Show output</a>\n")
                    .append("\n<a href=\"#").append(divId).append("\"")
                    .append(" onClick=\"toggleAllBoxes();\">Show all outputs</a>\n")
                    ;

                  // Method output
                  pw.append("<div class='log' id=\"").append(divId).append("\">\n");
                  for (String s : output) {
                    pw.append(s).append("<br/>\n");
                  }
                  pw.append("</div>\n");
                }
              }

              pw.append("</td>\n");


              // Exception
              tw = tr.getThrowable();
              String stackTrace;
              String fullStackTrace;

              id = "stack-trace" + tr.hashCode();
              pw.append("<td>");

              if (null != tw) {
                fullStackTrace = Utils.longStackTrace(tw, true);
                stackTrace = "<div><pre>" + Utils.shortStackTrace(tw, true)  + "</pre></div>";

                pw.append(stackTrace);
                // JavaScript link
                pw.append("<a href='#' onClick='toggleBox(\"")
                .append(id).append("\", this, \"Click to show all stack frames\", \"Click to hide stack frames\")'>")
                .append("Click to show all stack frames").append("</a>\n")
                .append("<div class='stack-trace' id='").append(id).append("'>")
                .append("<pre>").append(fullStackTrace).append("</pre>")
                .append("</div>")
                ;
              }

              pw.append("</td>\n");

              // Time
              long time = (tr.getEndMillis() - tr.getStartMillis()) / 1000;
              String strTime = Long.toString(time);
              pw.append("<td>").append(strTime).append("</td>\n");

              // Instance
              Object instance = tr.getInstance();
              pw.append("<td>").append(Objects.toString(instance)).append("</td>");

              pw.append("</tr>\n");
            }

            pw.append("</table><p>\n");

          }

}
```

Comment: And are you using a suitable version of the library?

Comment: Yes, i am using latest version `testng 6.10` through `pom.xml`

Comment: Does "mvn clean compile" from CMD work? if so, this might just be an eclipse issue (That may be solved by looking at project dependencies from eclipse UI)

Comment: Could you paste your class also?

Comment: I edited above to include class

Comment: I did not get any error with IntelliJ IDEA, I think it is a problem related with Eclipse. You can try Intellij IDEA

Comment: Thank you for confirming, at least I know its an eclipse thing. I'll search and  try and error

Comment: Works for me on Eclipse as well. As per above suggestion can you check the dependency hierarchy on your pom.xml whether the expected TestNg version added with the right scope and check mvn compile as well? Also Eclipse can add TestNG dependency to build path (maybe with an older version), can you check the project/properties/build libraries for an unexpected TestNg dependency?

Comment: How do i do `mvn compile` ? I copy-pasted eclipse project into a different location and ran `mvn compile` from directory where `pom.xml` reside. got  errors. is that the right way?

Comment: @user1207289 Are they the same error you see in Eclipse? Or what kind of errors? To compile the project you should be able to run `mvn clean compile` from the folder where the pom.xml is.

Comment: first time , I got some error, after reading , I deleted `.m2/repository` folder content and ran again just now, and got - `src/firsttestngpackage/FirstTestNGFile.java:[4,30] package org.testng.annotations does not exist`.  These errors were not there in eclispe

Comment: seems like all 41 errors are related to `package org.testng does not exist` and its repercussions

Comment: Try `mvn clean install -U`
For some reason the TestNg is not downloaded that is what causing this problem.
If you got the same issue during the first run, that seems to indicate, that it not problem in Eclipse, but some dependency issue.
Hopefully updating the dependencies with `-U` will download TestNG again.

Comment: I just happen to change to `<scope>compile</scope>` instead of  `<scope>test</scope>` in `pom` for `testng` and it compiled and it ran.  So , seems the original issue is with eclipse. At least I can do something  from command line now.

Comment: @user1207289 - I believe that you may have to upgrade your TestNG eclipse plugin to the latest version. By default TestNG eclipse plugin will use the TestNG jar that is embedded in the plugin, but I used to be able to change that by going into `Settings > TestNG` and choosing `Use Project jar`. It may have changed now. Been a long time since I used eclipse.

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan, TestNG eclipse plugin respects the project classpath, as you see there's no "Use Projet Jar" properties any more since 6.9.11.201603260617.          Back to PO question, I think `<scope>compile</scope>` does the tricks.  it's more like a m2e thing. I guess `CustomReport.java` is under `src/main/java` not `src/test/java`

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan Thanks. updating plugin resolved the error.  My listener classes are  only executing when I right click  on testng.xml and run but when I run same code by right clicking maven project (eclipse hierarchy) and run as `testng Test` , the listener classes do not run. Any idea, why am I experiencing that?

Comment: nevermind please . [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835790/using-custom-reporters-with-the-maven-surefire-plugin/11837438#11837438) worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per suggestion in above comments

updating testNG plugin through eclipse help--> check for updates --> then selecting testNG and updating, resolved the error